# License links are not HTTPS in README files of Developer Surveys

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, ssl, stack-overflow-developer-survey

I was having a look at the [2020 Stack Overflow Developer Survey Results](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey) and noticed that the license links in *README_2020.txt* are not HTTPS. The links seem to be the same in the previous surveys too.

> This database - The Public 2020 Stack Overflow Developer Survey
> Results - is made available under the Open Database License (ODbL):
> **http**://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1.0/. Any rights in
> individual contents of the database are licensed under the Database
> Contents License: **http**://opendatacommons.org/licenses/dbcl/1.0/

Comment: But luckily the maintainers of opendatacommons.org have automatic redirects to https configured.